# Form in Symfony is fully displayed, instead of just some parts?

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to only show some parts of a form, but the form is always fully rendered, with all the fields, instead of just showing the fields I want to display. Would you know why?

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_label(form.title) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}




$form = $this->createFormBuilder($advert)
    ->add('date', DateType::class, array(
        'widget' => 'text',
        'label'  => 'custom Date',
    ))
    ->add('title', TextType::class)
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
    ->getForm();

  return $this->render('OCPlatformBundle:Advert:edit.html.twig', array(
    'form'   => $form->createView(),
    'advert' => $advert
  ));
```

The result is : the date and the title are displayed, both with the label and the html value.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`form_end()` also outputs `form_rest()`, which renders all fields that have not yet been rendered for the given form: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-rest-view-variables

If you don't want to render the unrendered fields, add `{'render_rest': false}` to `form_end`:

```
 {{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexandru Furculita

Answer (score 1):

You can display only some part of ***[form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html)***

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}

    {{ form_row(form.first) }}
    {{ form_row(form.second) }}
    ...

    {{ form_row(form.submit, { 'label': 'Submit me' }) }}
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

If you wanna remove fields, you can remove fields in **Controller** example:

```
$form->remove("your fields");
```

Comment: This will not help as all fields that have not been rendered explicitly will still be rendered when calling `form_end()` (due to its call to `form_rest()` as explained by Alexandru Furculita).

Comment: Thanks for the answer